# SQLite Concurrency with Python?

Tags: python, sqlite, concurrency

Suppose that I have a huge SQLite file (say, 500[MB]). Can 10 different `python` instances access this file **at the same time** and ***update different records*** of it?. Note, the emphasis here is on *different records*.

For example, suppose that the SQLite file has say `1M` rows:

instance 1 will deal with (and update) rows 0 - 100000

instance 2 will will deal with (and update) rows 100001 - 200000

.........................

instance 10 will deal with (and update) rows 900001 - 1000000

---

Meaning, each `python` instance will only be updating a unique subset of the file. Will this work, or will I have serious integrity issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated, thanks to André Caron.**

You **can** do that, **but** only read operations supports concurrency in SQLite, since entire database is locked on any write operation. SQLite engine will return SQLITE_BUSY status in this situation (if it exceeds default timeout for access). Also consider that this heavily depends on how good file locking is implemented for given OS and file system. In general I wouldn't recommend to use proposed solution, especially considering that DB file is quite large, but you can try.

It will be better to use server process based database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.) to implement desired app behaviour.

Comment: The SQLite FAQ clearly explains that SQLite uses reader/writer locks, allowing concurrent access.  Writes are serialized, but concurrency with write access **is** supported.

Comment: I agree, however, in general, concurrent write access to SQLite db is not very safe (depends how good is file locking is implemented for given OS and FS).

Comment: "entire database is locked on any write operation" is usually not for very long. Especially with journaling enabled, it's tens of milliseconds at most while the journal is flushed, and even then, reads should still succeed.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat.  Only one instance can write at any single time, which means concurrent writes will block (refer to the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)).  You won't get integrity issues, but I'm not sure you'll really benefit from concurrency, although that depends on how much you write versus how much you read.